# studentSchema is not defined in multi tenants database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> I encountered an issue while accessing the collection in my multi-tenant app's database, based on university name. The error message states that the "studentSchema" is not defined in middleware.

here is my API that creates university :

```
app.use('/universities', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const name = 'ohio'
        const existingUniversity = await University.findOne({ name })
        if (existingUniversity) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'University already exists' })
        }

        const university = new University({ name })
        await university.save()

        const universityDBURI = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${name}`
        const universityDBConnection = mongoose.createConnection(
            universityDBURI,
            {
                useNewUrlParser: true,
                useUnifiedTopology: true,
            }
        )

        await universityDBConnection.createCollection('students')

        res.status(201).json(university)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
        res.status(500).json({ error })
    }
})
```

This is my middleware where I got error:

```
const multiTenant = async (req, res, next) => {
    const universityName = 'ohio'

    const university = await University.findOne({ name: universityName })

    if (!university) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'University not found' })
    }

    const universityDBURI = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${university.name}`
    const universityDBConnection = await mongoose.createConnection(
        universityDBURI,
        {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }
    )
    console.log('universityDBConnection', universityDBConnection)
    const Student = await universityDBConnection.model('Student', studentSchema)
    req.model = Student
    req.university = university

    next()
}
```

This is my students API:

```
app.get('/students', multiTenant, async (req, res) => {
    const Student = req.model

    try {
        const students = await Student.find()
        res.json(students)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch students' })
    }
})
```

Students model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    university: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'University' },
})

const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema)

module.exports = Student
```

Comment: Why do you use `await universityDBConnection.model`? You should just use the declared `Student` model